# How to retrieve data broadcasted via Laravel broadcastWith() in Livewire?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, pusher

I defined the [broadcast data](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/broadcasting#broadcast-data) via `broadcastWith()` in my event:

```php
    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'value' => $this->value,
        ];
    }
```

I can receive the event in Livewire via `getListeners()`:

```php
    public function getListeners()
    {
        return [
            "echo:counters,.CounterUpdated" => 'refreshCounter',
        ];
    }
```

However, how can I access the data (i.e. `name`, `value`) within the event?

As a note, the data is passed correctly, as I can receive them via Javascript:

```js
window.Echo.channel('counters')
    .subscribed(() => {
        console.log("Subscriped " + "counters");
    })
    .listen('.CounterUpdated', (e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The broadcasted data is passed to the callback function directly:

```php
    public function refreshCounter($data)
    {
        $this->count += $data['value'] ?? 0;
    }
```